# How do you create lies that contains truth inside?

Tags: characters

There is one thing I did not like to admit: I don't know how to lie.

I could make up some random excuses but it wouldn't be convincing enough. And there is always a saying that I can't manage to get my head around: The best lies contain some of the truth inside.

My character is trying to cook up some believable story to cover up someone's absence and he's failing it because he can't be believable enough and the fault was mine. I would like people to explain the art of lying to me so I could get past this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at lying as a deliberate act of deception, a calculated attempt to mislead another person's understanding away from a truth that you do not want revealed.
It is likely that you are troubled by the goal of the liar, not by the action of lying.

As a fiction writer, you create worlds that don't exist, characters who never lived and events which never happened.  In other words, you lie.   But you do so with the intent of entertaining your reader, and maybe of teaching some greater truth which is easier conveyed in soft non-factual stories than in stark empirically-accurate reports.

It is an issue of intent rather than content.

So for a person of moral character, the best lie is not the one that contains an element of truth.  It instead contains more noble elements such as kindness, concern or even allegiance to some higher purpose.  It would be wonderfully revealing to introduce a character who has trouble lying about little things but can mislead without hesitation when the stakes are worth it.  They might not even realize why they handle the different situations so differently, but an attentive reader will pick up on it and come to recognize that that character is honest enough to only lie when necessary, yet self-assured enough to lie affectively when it is important.

So as a more general solution...  To craft a character who can lie affectively in a given situation, craft their morality and their world view such that the minor sin of lying pales by comparison to the greater relative damage that can be caused by the truth.

On the high moral ground, that covers the saintly soon-to-be-martyr who chooses to lie by omission in not telling the serial killer where his innocent victim is hiding.

Down in the moral mud where most of us live, it also covers the horny teenager who lies about the hot girl's reason for missing class because he knows that she won't like him if he shares the truth.

Ultimately it is not a question of IF your character will lie.  We all lie.  It is a question of WHY your character will lie.  Reach inside your character's world and figure out what they value enough to lie about.  Once you do that, they will join the rest of us on the slippery slope of justified falsehood.

Comment: I just picked up a book by John Dufresne, a great writer and writing teacher, about writing fiction  -- "The Lie that Tells a Truth"

Answer (score 1):

### It's not a lie so much as storytelling...

To have a character tell a lie is actually a lot easier than it might seem. You, as the storyteller, control the world. There are a variety of ways you can make even a weak lie seem like a convincing one.

- Simply make the person lied to believe the lie. You decide if they believe it.
- As the master of the universe, you control what is or isn't true. So even if "She twisted an ankle and had to go to the doctor," sound unconvincing to you, you simply MAKE it convincing - the person being discussed really did twist their ankle, but it was a couple days ago. You MADE reality different to conform to the need for a convincing lie. In a strange way, you are the truth, and you added truth to the lie to make it truthy.
- Agatha Christy used appeal to authority a lot to credence to her writing. The felon might not be convincingly clever, but if the police are stumped, it's good enough and supports the assumption of cleverness. If the inspector says Ms. Marple is brilliant, then when she jumps to the desired conclusion with insufficient evidence, the reader suspends disbelief and accepts that Ms. Marple put together the tiny clues and determined which bits of evidence were important, and which not.
- Change the lie when you come up with a better one. While the character has a few seconds to come up with a glib response, you can take all the time you want. Editing means you can endlessly change what you are writing until it's exactly the way you like. A lot of writers will use placeholders in their stories for things they can't think of at the time, then fill things back in later when they come up with it. If you're anything like me, one night you'll bolt up in bed saying, "She had a flat tire and called to let everyone know she couldn't make it!"

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather difficult to answer in an objective manner. I'll try to contribute in a more mathematical manner than others. As it would be really hard to explain how all this works in a regular-sized answer, I'll have to recommend a handful of books.

The first thing you have to discern is if your character is lying on purpose or not. Secondly, how good he is supposed to be at it. Who are they? What do they do for a living?

Assuming the character is supposed to be good at it, I'll recommend you to do some studying the matter. I am not a big fan of the "how to manipulate everybody in some easy steps" sort of books, so I have no recommendation. A book comes to mind, though. It is about "the art" of seducing women. Quite misogynistic and I couldn't really finish reading it, but it's full of wisdom in that realm. The name is The Game: Penetrating the Secret Society of Pick-up Artists. It is basically the "real" story of a journalist infiltrating a seduction-science cult and getting absorbed by it. There is lying all around, as you can imagine. It is easy to read; written as a narrative, pretty much.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game:_Penetrating_the_Secret_Society_of_Pickup_Artists
There is also a related American reality TV show called The Pickup Artist. I am sure it's pretty horrible, but probably an interesting thing to watch anthropologically speaking.

Apart from immersing yourself in a book written by a liar, my next advice is probably healthier and more interesting. Have a look at logical fallacies, logical paradoxes and cognitive biases. They are the base of deception; both when lying on purpose and when you simply deceive yourself and others by mistake. Remember that the only reason Aristotle invented the modern idea of Logic was for the purposes of proving the sophists were professional liars and beat them in debates. It is a wonder no parliament does this anymore, though. But that's another story!

By studying cognitive biases you can really get inspiration into how to make your character deceive anybody; including themselves. For instance, unconscious bias (also called Implicit stereotype) is the basis for many group-based prejudices. You can very well play with that cognitive bias and your characters opinion of what's good and evil in their world. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_stereotype
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias#List_of_biases

Logical paradoxes are rather interesting too. What you are asking might have much to do with that. Think of Plato's memorable "I only know I know nothing". Biggest truth or biggest lie in human history? It is about perception, really.
https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/brain-workout/202010/what-is-logical-paradox

The study of logic, in general, could be of great help to understand how the statements of truth work; therefore how lying works too. For an easy read, I recommend Logic Made Easy How to Know When Language Deceives You by Deborah J. Bennett. This PDF is rather dense and mathematical, but it can be a great read too:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47757658_On_the_Logic_of_Lying

The study of rhetoric can also prove useful in order to know how lying works. Look at politicians. They still teach this sort of things in Oxbridge for a reason. All this has been part of classical education for centuries; only until recently, really. We all would be considered ignorants by any medieval scholar nowadays; ironically enough. For easy reads, you can start with Words Like Loaded Pistols Rhetoric from Aristotle to Obama by Sam Leith. It has plenty of particular examples of public speaking lying.

For logical fallacies, besides Wikipedia and other online sources, you can read Logically Fallacious by Bo Bennett
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy

I am aware I am not giving any easy solution to this. The basis of my answer is, pretty much, do some research. It is what makes being a writer interesting, in my opinion. It forces you to face what you know and what you don't. Research is great for inspiration too. If my recommendations feel too dense, I would just go for the autobiography of any well-known liar. If you pay attention you'll find many lies hiding some truth.

On a side note. In my opinion, showing the truth through lying is a rather good description of what fiction is. So, something interesting to look at!

Some more interesting links:

https://www.dwrl.utexas.edu/2016/10/27/the-language-of-lying/

https://www.juniata.edu/offices/juniata-voices/past-version/media/Telling-Lies-and-Inventing-Rhetoric-In-Ancient-Greece-David-Hutto-JuniataVoices.pdf

Comment: Slightly unrelated but extremely interesting article about cognitive bias in narration; what is called the narrative fallacy. It is curious how much in common story-telling and things like psychosis can have. It is all about lying to oneself without noticing. 
https://medium.com/@coffeeandjunk/cognitive-bias-narrative-fallacy-9cff93a597b2